# How to get Id from ComboBox in C# windows Form Application

Tags: c#, combobox, c#-2.0

I have a `ComboBox` filled this way:

```
List<Category> CategList = new Category().getAllCategory();

foreach (Category cat in CategList)
{            
    ComboForCategory.Items.Add(cat.CategoryName);
}
```

The `ComboBox` displays all `CategoryName` details successfully... now I need to get `CategoryID` from selected `Name`...

Then I used to get `CategoryID` like this:

```
Item ob = new Item();
ob.category.CategoryId = ComboForCategory.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

But it shows errors. Why? How to get `CategoryID` from selected `Name`?

Answer (score 1):

In the code behind you need to specify the ValueMember property. You can then use the DisplayMember to specify which property of the object you want displayed.

```
List<Category> CategList = new Category().getAllCategory();

ComboForCategory.DataSource = CategList;
ComboForCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
ComboForCategory.ValueMember = "CategoryId";
```

Then when you want to grab the SelectedValue you can call it like this:

```
ob.category.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(ComboForCategory.SelectedValue);
```

(using ToString() is not necessary).

Comment: You said this is for a Windows Forms application, yet this answer is for a Web Forms application.  Please specify which.

Comment: I tested this in a Windows form application and it worked just fine. If you have errors there is something else causing them. Can you post a screenshot of the errors youre getting?

Comment: I just noticed that you tagged your question under "c# 2.0", this answer is done using .Net Framework 4.

Comment: Its done using framework 4.5 so that could be the reason why it does not work for you.